# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [354, 152] when printing the R2 scores

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a model and then print it's R^2 score for train and test sets, but when I want to print the R2 score, I get the error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [354, 152] .
My code is the following:

```
X = np.transpose(np.matrix(dataset.RM))
y = np.transpose(np.matrix(dataset.MEDV))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=21) 
linear_reg = LinearRegression(normalize=True, n_jobs=-1)

model = linear_reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(r2_score(X_train, X_test))
print(r2_score(y_train, y_test))
```

I also tried to print the sizes of the train and test sets, and I get these outputs for them:

```
print(X_train.shape)  -> (354, 1)
print(X_test.shape)   -> (152, 1)
print(y_train.shape)  -> (354, 1)
print(y_test.shape)   -> (152, 1)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I print my R2 scores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
model = linear_reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(r2_score(y_train, model.transform(X_train)))
print(r2_score(y_test, model.transform(X_test)))
```

to print the `r^2` score of `train` and `test` data.

If your `model` is sklearn object which does not have `transform` you can use `predict`

Comment: It tells me this when I use the code provided by you: LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'transform'

Comment: do you know what I could do?